# MySQL Limit Select Statement

Tags: mysql

Here an example Table:

```
+--------+------------+
| itemID | itemvalue  |
+--------+------------+
|      1 |          a |
|      2 |          b |
|      3 |          a |
|      4 |          a |
|      5 |          b |
|      6 |          a |
|      7 |          b |
|      8 |          a |
|      9 |          a |
|     10 |          b |
+--------+------------+
```

I like to know how many 'a' are in the first 5 rows of the table. So in words should do the following:

Select **only the first 5 rows** from table X WHERE itemvalue = a

This should return rows 1, 3 and 4

Is it possible to do this with just a Mysql Query and without further computing?

Comment: Do you mean the first 5 rows orderd by `itemID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one idea:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(itemID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,itemvalue CHAR(1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
( 1,'a'),
(2,'b'),
(3,'a'),
(4,'a'),
(5,'b'),
(6,'a'),
(7,'b'),
(8,'a'),
(9,'a'),
(10,'b');
```

...

```
 WITH cte AS
 (
 SELECT *
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY itemid) x 
   FROM my_table
 )
 SELECT itemID,itemvalue FROM cte WHERE x <=5 AND itemvalue = 'a';
 +--------+-----------+
 | itemID | itemvalue |
 +--------+-----------+
 |      1 | a         |
 |      3 | a         |
 |      4 | a         |
 +--------+-----------+
```

Comment: You're in good company, because neither do I! However, further insight can be gained by executing the 'cte' bit on its own.

Answer (score 4):

You can try with using an inner join query to do it

```
select t1.* from my_table t1
join
(select itemId from my_table order by itemId limit 5) t2
on t1.itemID=t2.itemID
where t1.itemvalue='a'
```

**[Working demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bfKgj5rXjdZ5gf98hJK1Um/1)**

Comment: Thanks for your help but the result is: MySQL Error: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery.

My MySQL Version is 8.0.25.

But radocaws Soluition worked for my as well.

Answer (score -1):

```
  SELECT * FROM table X WHERE itemvalue = a LIMIT $startingOffset, $count"
```

here in your case count is 5 and pass starting offset.
if u pass 10 as starting offset it will fetch first 5 rows with starting index of 11

Comment: That would just give you all a rows until the limit is reached. The question was how to check if the first 5 rows have the value `a`.